# Generating unique sequence numbers in the browser for logging

Tags: javascript, security, logging, distributed-computing

When creating distributed systems one of the major issues is debugging where and how issues arise, and often the only tool you have for doing post-mortems are the available logs. One way of trying to deal with combining logs from different systems is [generating a unique sequence number](http://highscalability.com/log-everything-all-time) that follows a request through the system.

One minor issue with this is finding out where to draw the boundary on where a request starts. If one says this boundary starts in the browser, then that leaves the generation of the unique identifier up to the browser, using [some GUID library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid). Would that be a feasible solution, or should I rethink this?

Answer (score 1):

As you put the security tag on the question, let me shed some light on the security aspect. If you choose to generate unique ids in the browser, a malicious client (an attacker) can totally mess up your logs by sending ids as he wishes (the same for all requests for example, or mixing them up more cleverly). So it's important to keep in mind that anything in a request to a web app is fully in the control of the client, which can also forge any request field, be it a header or contents.

So to keep logs (especially if this includes security-related logs too), I would generate ids on the web server, there is no way for the browser to do this securely.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of putting the client in control, but good point about enabling a malicious client to mess up the logs willfully.